# How can you prevent ogr2ogr from truncating trailing zeros when setting coordinate_precision=0 and saving to GeoJSON?

Tags: ogr2ogr

This weekend I started using ogr2ogr and discovered that it's a great tool for converting from one spatial reference system to another. I used it to convert a shapefile to GeoJSON, from WGS84 to a NAD83 stateplane, and wanted decimals truncated, but I discovered that its "smart truncation" feature then truncated the trailing zeros on the resulting integers (e.g., 1100000 was written as 11). I searched the web for a while, but wasn't able to find a command-line argument that would avoid this issue.

Below is the full command I was running. My short-term solution was to set the precision to 1 and then use a regex on the resulting file to truncate decimals.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" CTABusStops.json -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:102671 -select
OBJECTID,STOP_ID,STREET,CROSS_ST,DIR,POS,ROUTESSTPG,PUBLIC_NAM -where STATUS=1 -lco
coordinate_precision=0 CTA_BusStops.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the answer is to update GDAL. At least I cant't repeat the error with GDAL 1.11

Without coordinate_precision

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON"  geojsontest1.json -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -select ID  geojsontest.shp
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 340 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1669792.3618991044, -1689200.1396078952 ] } },
```

With coordinate_precision=0

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON"  geojsontest2.json -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -select ID -lco coordinate_precision=0 geojsontest.shp
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 340 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1669792, -1689200 ] } },
```